# How to set up two-factor authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 and Katana correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, katana

In the code that you get in the ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 templates with Visual Studio 2015 Community RC, if you run them as they came, and if you register with your email address (and *not* with an external service provider such as Facebook or Google or Linked In or Twitter), and then if you login into the website by entering your user name and password, it straight-away lets you login and does not trigger two-factor authentication. It just logs you in successfully.

Specifically, the `PasswordSignInAsync` method on the `SignInManager` always returns a `SignInStatus` of `Success` if you enter your correct user name and password. It never evaluates to `SignInStatus.RequiresVerification`.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, 
                                      string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, 
    // change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                      model.Email, model.Password, 
                      model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            // if I sign-in with my correct user name
            // and password, the flow-of-control always
            // comes here. The SignInStatus never evaluates
            // to RequiresVerification
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            // the flow-of-control never reaches here
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", 
                                    new 
                                    { 
                                      ReturnUrl = returnUrl, 
                                      RememberMe = model.RememberMe 
                                     });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

This happens even though the default code has got two-factor authentication enabled and set up as indicated by the following snippets of code.

**In Startup.ConfigureAuth**

```
app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, 
                                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
```

**In ApplicationUserManager.Create, the factory method.**

```
// Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone 
// and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
// You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", 
                        new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
{
    MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
});
manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", 
                        new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
{
    Subject = "Security Code",
    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
});

var container = Unity.Container;
manager.EmailService = container.Resolve<EmailService>();
manager.SmsService = container.Resolve<SmsService>();
```

I've got my `EmailService` and `SmsService` set up in a Unity container and they're configured properly.

What else do I need to do to set it up correctly? I have read [this article](http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/04/asp-net-identity-2-0-two-factor-authentication/) and a few pieces of documentation from the MSDN, and a few forums posts on other websites about setting this up, but I am not very certain if I am missing something.

**This guy isn't called / redirected to from anywhere. I guess this is what's missing.**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EnableTwoFactorAuthentication()
{
    await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), 
                                               true);
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (user != null)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, 
                                        rememberBrowser: false);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
}
```

It does seem that I am missing the part where I have to specifically have the user call the `EnableTwoFactorAuthentication` action as there is currently no call to it, but I can't be sure how that should integrate with the rest of the login workflow.

Comment: On the userManager configurations, have you set UserLockoutEnabledByDefault to true? Doing so prevents new users to login before email confirmation (you also have to manually check if the user is locked out with userManager.IsLockedOut)

Answer (score 0):

Click f12 from your browser and delete  application Cookies